# Sending response in loop using send function

Tags: c, webserver

I am trying to implement a web server in C. I am sending a response of a request using the send command in a loop.

```
buf_len = 1;  
          while (buf_len > 0)  
          {
            buf_len = read(fh, out_buf, BUF_SIZE);
            if (buf_len > 0)   
            { 
              send(client_s, out_buf, buf_len, 0);     
              
            }
          }
```

Should I terminate the last character of by  `char out_buf[BUF_SIZE]` with `'\0'`.
Also when I am trying to send a png file with the same code, Sometimes I receive the entire image and sometimes only half of it. It loads fully when I refresh the page.

Comment: No need to terminate with a zero.

Comment: @CharlieBurns Can you please answer the second part two. Why do I get partial image sometimes and complete image appears only if I refresh the page once or twice.

Answer (score 0):

For send function, see man page

RETURN VALUE
       On success, these calls return the number of characters sent.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is  set  appropriately.

So it doesn't guarantee that buf_len bytes are sent out, you can check the return value.

Answer (score 0):

As Hardy said above, send does not guarantee that buf_len bytes are sent out. So one of many ways to do it is

```
      buf_len = 1;  
      while (buf_len > 0) {
        buf_len = read(fh, out_buf, BUF_SIZE);
        if(buf_len < 0) {
            perror("read");
            exit(1);
        }
        int sent = 0;
        int count = buf_len;
        while(count) {
           int n = send(client_s, out_buf + sent, count, 0);
           count -= n;
           sent += n;
        }
      }
```

How is out_buf defined?

Comment: out_buf is char array. I tried the way you have mentioned above. Still facing the same problem.

Comment: How exactly is it defined? Also, don't ignore compiler warnings. Got any of those?

Comment: Depending on how out_buf is defined you could change the send line to "int n = send(client_s, &out_buf[sent], count, 0);"

Comment: I had used the send line as above only. Sorry I am not getting what you mean by how it is defined. If you are asking about the declaration, then it is declared like this
char out_buf[100];

Comment: Try this send line: int n = send(client_s, &out_buf[sent], count, 0);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40407/discussion-between-dilip-and-charlie-burns)

Comment: Not sure what to suggest, this block of code looks ok to me. Maybe post another StackOverflow question. This time include the entire function and how it is called. Or, even better, read this http://sscce.org/